# How to pass ints and char variables to function in command line

Tags: c, linux

I wrote a function where you pass two integers and an operator character (+-*/) and give a result of the two numbers. The code takes the character and checks it using its ascii value. If I pass a number in place of the operator (42 instead of *) then it works, but I don't know how to pass it as a char because the function has int argc and int * argv parameters (the function prototype was written by an instructor.) How do I make it so I can pass the char straight from the command line?

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int result;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    printf("main_add pid: %d\n", getpid());
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    char c;
    //printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
    //printf("%s\n", argv[2]);
    //printf("%s\n", argv[3]);
    a = atoi(argv[1]);
    b = atoi(argv[2]);
        c = atoi(argv[3]);
    
    if (c=='*'){
    result = a * b;
    
    printf("%d * %d = %d\n", a, b, result);
    }
    else if(c=='+'){
    result = a + b;

    printf("%d + %d = %d\n", a, b, result);
    }
    else if(c=='-'){
    result = a - b;

    printf("%d - %d = %d\n", a, b, result);
    }
    else if(c=='/'){
    result = a / b;
    
    printf("%d / %d = %d\n", a, b, result);
    }
    else{
    printf("fail");
    }
}
```[enter image description here][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0eiN.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ij5FR.png
````

Comment: What do you mean? Don't convert the char to an integer, but simply pass the arguments as required: `./yourprogram '1' '2' '+';` `./yourprogram '7' '6' '*';` In your program use `argv[3]` to access the third argument.

Comment: Your issue is that you are calling atoi on c which is not supposed to be a number. You want c to simply be the string at argv3

Comment: "... and int * argv..."  No, you don't.

Comment: Don't repeat yourself.  You only need one `printf`: `printf("%d %c %d = %d\n", a, c, b, result);`. (There are a lot of other refactors that should happen, but that's a good place to start.)

Answer (score 1):

> the function has int argc and int * argv parameters (the function prototype was written by an instructor.)

That was *not* written by an instructor, in the sense of having been devised by one of *your* instructors.  `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` is one of only two standard variants for the signature of the entry point to a C program, and the only one of them that provides for handling command-line arguments.

> How do I make it so I can pass the char straight from the command line?

Your program *already* receives character data from the command line, in the form of C strings.  Why else do you think it makes sense to *convert* some of those strings to numbers via `atoi()`?

But what purpose do you think is served by applying `atoi()` to an argument that you do not expect to have the form of a numeric string?  That is exactly what produces ...

> If I pass a number in place of the operator (42 instead of *) then it works

... which is not what you want.

The `argv` array contains pointers to strings from which the characters of the command-line arguments can be read.  If you want to read the characters of the arguments then do so directly.  For example,

```
c = argv[3][0];
```

You would be wise, however, to first verify, by checking the value of `argv`, that at least 3 arguments were actually passed.  Since `argv` also provides the program name, that means you're looking for `argv` to be at least 4.

Answer (score 1):

The C standard defines only two valid declarations for the `main` function. They are `int main(void)`, which is for programs that do not accept command-line inputs and `int main(int args, char *argv[])` for programs that do.

In the second case `int args` will represent the number of elements in the C-string array `char *argv[]`, which is an array of pointers to C-string representations of each of the arguments. As to the *how do I pass a character to my program directly from the command line* question, you are forced to use the string representation, but this is of little consequence.

Let's assume you compile the program and call it "calculator.elf"

If you were to run: `./calculator.elf 2 7 *`

Your `main` function would be informed of these arguments by being passed a `args` with the value 4, and an `argv[]` with four pointers to C strings. The first one would be `"./calculator.elf"`, the second `"2"`, the third `"7"`, and the fourth `"*"`.

You are correct by looking in indices 1, 2 and 3 to look for your arguments because you have no need for the name of your program as an argument, and `atoi("2")` and `atoi("7")` should give you 2 and 7 respectively, but `atoi("*")` is not going to give you a useful result because `"*"` is not a numerical string.

Keep in mind that `"*"` is a string, not a single character, so `argv[3]` is going to be a pointer to a `'*'` character which is immediately followed by a `'\0'` character.

A valid check to see if you were passed `"*"` in `argv[3]` would be `strcmp(argv[3],"*") == 0` or `argv[3][0] == '*' && argv[3][1] == '\0'`, but `atoi(argv[3])` should return 0 in accordance with the C specification for `atoi` in the case that it is passed a pointer to a non-numerical string